# Sizing Image inside Word Document using Openxml SDK .Net c#

Tags: image, size, width, openxml, cpu-word

I added an image to my generated word document using openxml sdk, but iam not able to size that image to word document full width respecting the image ratio.

How can i get the word document width? And what is the best aproach to achieve this task!?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it that way now and it works fine:

```
// Scaling down the Image
SectionProperties? sectionProperties = null; 
PageSize? pageSize = null;
long pageWidth = 0;

if (main.Document.Body is { })
    sectionProperties = main.Document.Body.GetFirstChild<SectionProperties>();

if (sectionProperties is { }) 
    pageSize = sectionProperties.GetFirstChild<PageSize>();

if (pageSize is { Width: { } } && pageSize is { Height: { } }) 
    pageWidth = pageSize.Width;

if (pageWidth > width) {
    var sizeFactor = pageWidth / width;
    width = (int)pageWidth;
    height = (int)(sizeFactor * height);
}

double englishMetricUnitsPerInch = 914400;
double pixelsPerInch = 96;
double factor = englishMetricUnitsPerInch / pixelsPerInch;

/*
 * MS-Docs (OpenXml SDK, PageSize Class)
 * This output states that all pages in this section must be 11907 twentieths of 
 * a point wide (11907 twentieths of a point = 8.269") and 16839 twentieths of a 
 * point high (16939 twentieths of a point = 11.694"). end example]
 */
double emuWidth = (width * factor) / 20; 
double emuHeight = (height * factor) / 20;
```

The inside the drawing element:

```
Extent = new() {
    Cx = (Int64Value)emuWidth,
    Cy = (Int64Value)emuHeight
},
```